# how to handle SMS SENT event?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm writing an app that sends sms using SmsManager. How can I get informations about success of this operation? Is there a BroadcastReceiver for "sms sent" events?

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On devices that use the default Android SMS manager, you should have a `content://sms/sent` provider. If you create a ContentObserver on that provider URL you should be able to receive notifications about sent SMS messages.

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't know what's ContentObserver but I'm going to learn it ;)